# How to push to github with custom commit message with npm scripts?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-scripts

In my `package.json` I have this

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp serve",
    "git": "git add . && git commit -m 'some-message' && git push --all"
  },
```

In the terminal I run `npm run git` and the changes are pushed. But how can I change the commit message on the fly? For example `npm run git MESSAGE='another commit'`

Comment: you need to modify the command in package.json to git commit -m 'some message'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A solution involving some npm trickery might consist of:

```
"scripts": {
  "git": "git add . && git commit -m",
  "postgit": "git push --all"
},
```

To be called like:

```
npm run git -- "Message of the commit"
```

or:

```
npm run git -- Message
```

Comment: just to mention that postgit uses a post hook and is always called after the execution of git script