# How to pass arguments and use those arguments as variables in a package.json script?

Tags: git, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

```json
"scripts": {
    "cr": "git commit -am ${message} && git pull origin master --rebase && git push --force",
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to run the above with something like:

```
# yarn cr "commit message"
```

Comment: Seems like that would work better as a shell alias? Make sure to use `--force-with-lease` to avoid races.

Comment: You can try to modify the whole package.json file to substitute any of its part. You need to parse JSON first, then change the corresponding key value, then stringify the resulting JSON and save it to file.

Comment: There has to be a simple solution to this I feel like? And shell alias would work, but I want this to be easily re-usable by anyone who pulls down the project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
you can do something like this

```
"scripts": {
{
  "cr": "f(){ git commit -am $1;};f",

}
}
```

and `yarn run cr -- 'commit message'`

you can pass n number of arguments seperated with space and can be accesible via $1 ,$2 ..

Comment: This will fail on Windows when the default shell utilized by npm is `cmd.exe`

Comment: this will work on unix.
please use gitbash in windows

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `sh -c 'shell_command'` works on **nix* and *Windows Powershell*. Then, you can use `$0`, `$1`, and so on to access the command line arguments. So write this in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "cr": "sh -c 'git commit -am $0 && git pull origin master --rebase && git push --force'",
}
```

Now you can run this command in a terminal:

```
yarn cr commit_message
```

Comment: This will fail on Windows when the default shell utilized by npm is `cmd.exe`

Comment: Thanks for your point. I tested it on Ubuntu and Windows Powershell and it worked fine.

Comment: Sure Ubuntu is _*nix_ in which case npm uses `sh` by default. Powershell will typically use `cmd` by default. The [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) state: _"By default, on Unix-like systems it is the /bin/sh command, on Windows it is the cmd.exe."_. For true cross-platform compatibility you'll need to shell-out from a node.js script - for instance see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470546/pass-git-commit-message-to-npm-script-and-append-to-predefined-string).