# npm run build and if success then commit

Tags: git, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

how I need to set up package.json to check if build success then add and commit changes to git?

Current build:

```
"build": "react-scripts build"
```

Comment: Look up Husky, simple package that allows you to set up a pre commit command

Comment: Consider doing something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470546/pass-git-commit-message-to-npm-script-and-append-to-predefined-string/55494338#55494338) whereby you run e.g. `npm run buildAndCommit -- "commit message for a new build"` - whereby you pass the git commit message as an argument to the `npm run ...` command.

Comment: @RobC yes, tnx so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the answer:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-and-commit": "node -e \"const mssg = process.argv[1]; require('child_process').execSync('npm run build && git add . && git commit -m \\\"' + mssg + '\\\"', { stdio:[0, 1, 2] })\""
  }
```

Running like:

```
$ npm run build-and-commit -- "commit message"
```

or:

```
$ yarn build-and-commit -- "commit message"
```

Full answer here: [Pass git commit message to npm script and append to predefined string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470546/pass-git-commit-message-to-npm-script-and-append-to-predefined-string/55494338#55494338)

Tnx to [RobC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611459/robc)

Comment: In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470546/pass-git-commit-message-to-npm-script-and-append-to-predefined-string/55494338#55494338) that I previously provided, the reason for utilizing `node -e \" ... \"`, in the npm script  was because that question wanted to prefix the given git message with `BUILD - `. Given the variant in your answer doesn't do that it's unnecessary to utilize `node -e \" ... \"` in your npm script. Instead you can just define your npm script as;  `"build-and-commit": "npm run build && git add . && git commit -m"` - then run it with the same command

Comment: @RobC got error "error: switch `m' requires a value"

Comment: npm run build && git add . && git commit -m && git push -u origin staging

Comment: Sure, it will now because you've changed your compound command to `npm run build && git add . && git commit -m && git push -u origin staging`, However, I was referring to the example in your answer, which did not include the `&& git push -u origin staging` part.

Comment: @RobC its not possible to simplify it for command as i wrote?

Comment: Yes I know, it's not possible to simplify it for the compound commands that you wrote in the comments. The first comment I wrote regarding simplifying it was referring to the example commands provided in your answer.